# How to get session token form url?

Tags: java

Lets say.. 
if i hit google with https://www.google.com it will create a session, for the responce it

will create url with session tokn like..

https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=oFBjVJSvLqnM8gft5YDwAQ&gws_rd=ssl.

My question is 
am connecting to google with the code:

URL url = new URL(test);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

this will connect to google.
for this google creates a session.

then how would i get a session token back to my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the session token from the cookie of the browser. You can, find the cookie settings->advanced settings->privacy->content settings->allcookie and site data then search www.google.com and select sid and copy the content .

Answer (score 0):

You can extract any cookie, not only the one containing the session with the following approach:

Since a server may set multiple cookies in a single request, we will need to loop through the response headers, looking for all headers named "Set-Cookie".

```
String headerName=null;
for (int i=1; (headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
    if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
    String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);
```

The string returned by the getHeaderField(int index) method is a series of name=value separated by semi-colons (;). The first name/value pairing is actual data string we are interested in (i.e. "sessionId=0949eeee22222rtg"), the subsequent name/value pairings are meta-information that we would use to manage the storage of the cookie (when it expires, etc.).

```
    cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
    String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
    String cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
```

This is basically it. We now have the cookie name (cookieName) and the cookie value (cookieValue).

the above explanation was based on example provided in http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html#retrieving_cookies

A more sophisticated approach is to use CookieAccessor class:

```
public void getCookieUsingCookieHandler() { 
    try {       
        // Instantiate CookieManager;
        // make sure to set CookiePolicy
        CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
        manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

        // get content from URLConnection;
        // cookies are set by web site
        URL url = new URL("http://host.example.com");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.getContent();

        // get cookies from underlying
        // CookieStore
        CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
        List <HttpCookie> cookies =
            cookieJar.getCookies();
        for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
          System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get cookie using CookieHandler");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In any approach you follow you need to know what is the name of the cookie holding the session id, so that you can get the value from it. E.g a java web application usually creates a cookie with name "JSESSIOINID"